# MYSQL match field to another field with comma separated keywords

Tags: php, mysql, join

So I have two tables one is questions it has a description field that I am trying to match with the topics table search_keyword field.

For example the question table description field has this:

```
q.description 
-------------
Have you ever traveled to China?
```

And the search_keyword field on topics table has this:

```
t.search_keywords
-------------
travel, traveled, traveling, traveler, travel agency, jet set
```

So basically I am trying to narrow down a result set for questions based on the description having any of the keywords.

Here is my query so far, I am given the topic URL which is a field that narrows down things a bit, but then have to narrow down even more with matching the description to the search_keywords.

```
SELECT * FROM question q 
         LEFT JOIN topic t ON t.category_id = q.category_id 
         WHERE t.url = 'travel' AND 
         FIND_IN_SET(q.description, t.search_keywords)
```

NOTE: I can't change the database unfortunately

Any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

You should store the keywords as separate rows instead of comma separated values:

```
t.search_keywords
-------------
travel
traveled
traveling
traveler
travel agency
jet set
```

Then you can simply add `%` to both sides to find matches:

```
select *
from question q
left join topic t on t.category_id = q.category_id
where t.url = 'travel'
    and q.description like concat('%', t.search_keywords, '%');
```

Comment: i don't have that option, the database can't change unfortunately. If you could modify answer for comma that would be great thanks.

Comment: @JCLopez - This is the reason why normalization is so important.. You can follow [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/17942691/6348498) to convert CSV values into separate rows before joining.

Comment: i agree but its a stubborn client that doesn't want to change it. I saw the CSV values solution but doesn't seem to work on fiddle. I am trying to use RLIKE worst case I will have to use PHP to do this narrowing down of questions.

Comment: @JCLopez stubbon clients need practicalities explained to them, and a 200% charge increase to account for the excess stress they cause.

Comment: @Martin agreed! How can I upvote your comment?! It would so much better to redo their database it was created like 10 years ago by newbies it looks like.

Comment: @JCLopez *"Good morning. Your database and datasets where previously built by idiots, and I would like to restart your service with a proper build for XXX amount. Alternatively, if you'd like me to continue to use this unfit for purpose database build, I will need to charge you +250% extra for Stress Management Reasons. I'm sure you Understand."*